# How to add two buttons in the same line for Android?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I know that there are many similar questions but known of them worked for me. I want the `Turn Left` and `Turn Right` buttons to be on the same line. But here is what is being displayed:

[image]

Here is the code I have so far in my fragment_main.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/black">

    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="This is a simple button app. \r\n \r\nCode Here \r\n"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonGoStraight"
        android:layout_width="125dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/go_straight" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonTurnLeft"
        android:layout_width="125dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/turn_left" 
        android:layout_gravity="left"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonTurnRight"
        android:layout_width="125dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/turn_right" 
        android:layout_gravity="right"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonGoBack"
        android:layout_width="125dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/go_back" 
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="\n"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonGoBack"
        android:layout_width="125dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/destination" 
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

I am a beginner and don't know how to resolve this problem. Any suggestions?

Comment: not possible with one LinearLayout .. you can put second horizontal LinearLayout with two buttons or better try RelativeLayout

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have layout with vertical orientation. Use This

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/black">



    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="This is a simple button app. \r\n \r\nCode Here \r\n"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>

  <LinearLayout 
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/black">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonGoStraight"
        android:layout_width="125dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/go_straight" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonTurnLeft"
        android:layout_width="125dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/turn_left" 
        android:layout_gravity="left"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonTurnRight"
        android:layout_width="125dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/turn_right" 
        android:layout_gravity="right"/>
</LinearLayout> 

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the buttons into another LinearLayout that has `android:orientation` set to `horizontal`:

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:background="@android:color/black">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="This is a simple button app. \r\n \r\nCode Here \r\n"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonGoStraight"
        android:layout_width="125dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/go_straight" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="2">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonTurnLeft"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/turn_left"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonTurnRight"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/turn_right"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonGoBack"
        android:layout_width="125dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/go_back"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="\n"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonGoBack"
        android:layout_width="125dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/destination"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a layout like this if you want to keep your current button widths:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/black">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="This is a simple button app. \r\n \r\nCode Here \r\n"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonGoStraight"
        android:layout_width="125dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/go_straight" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="50">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonTurnLeft"
                android:layout_width="125dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/turn_left"
                android:layout_gravity="left"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="50">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonTurnRight"
                android:layout_width="125dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/turn_right"
                android:layout_gravity="right" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonGoBack"
        android:layout_width="125dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/go_back"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="\n"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonGoBack"
        android:layout_width="125dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/destination"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a RelativeLayout and specify toRightof. That way you don't use extra layout controls which will degrade your performance.